# MYSQL's "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" equivalent in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a MYSQL's `"FLUSH PRIVILEGES"` equivalent existing in SQL Server?

Or, are the changed permissions implicitly updated in SQL Server?

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks,
Bhathiya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server permissions are applied immediately, no need to flush anything. The moment a GRANT, REVOKE or DENY is issued it is in effect

Answer (score 2):

You should use FLUSH PRIVILEGES; only if you modify the grant tables directly using statements such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.

See: Stop using FLUSH PRIVILEGES